# Remove all CSS in a String (Javascript/Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I need to remove CSS of a string from the bodies of E-Mails, such that I get only the real message someone would read from that mail.

Many e-mails contain lots of HTML, which I already was able to strip using [striptags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags). However, the CSS remains. As an example mailbody:

> table.footer-table { width: 100%; font-size: inherit; line-height:
> 18px; text-align: center; }
>
> Dear Sir,
>
> Hello. Kind regards, John

As this is an example, in reality there are lots more CSS classes defined above the actual message.

I do not know what classes etc. will be in such mail (e.g. if it starts with table or whatever).

**Question**: How can the CSS be efficiently removed from the string?

I have not found a library yet which is able to do that.

Comment: First put the complete string without stripping off html

Comment: You can remove the styling from the html by using simple jquery script since most of the styling in emails are done inline. It might be something like 
    `$("table").removeAttr("style")`

Comment: @Paudel But this is not a very nice solution if I don't know the classes in advance.

Comment: @binariedMe I do not know how the mail will look in advance, I am looking for an allrounder solution.

Comment: you can strip off everything except for the table that you need and then you can go on to strip class attribute like the style one.

Comment: @ffritz is it really the content of your email? Isn't it any HTML markup in it? If not, I don't see how you will be able to tell the difference between CSS (without) markup and the email "real" content.

Comment: @Veve I just need the plaintext.

Comment: @ffritz I know you need the plain text, I'm asking you what you've got exactly as source.

Comment: @Veve This is the full example mail body: https://pastebin.com/HcU7HK9L

Comment: @Veve For this example, I found a way by simply removing the head, where the CSS is. Then using striptags, I get the plaintext.

Comment: Why make it so hard? There are modules that will do this better than regexs. For instance: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regexp to strip out the `<style>` block and its content.

Assuming the original content is stored in a variable `emailContent`, it could be like this:

```
var striptags = require('striptags');

stripedEmailContent = striptags(emailContent.replace(/<style.*<\/style>/g, ''));
```